# Delete table rows having selected id using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, delete-row

I am trying to make the code to add and remove desired rows on selecting id in the select box. My code is below :

HTML code :

```
<body>
        <table id="table" border="1" style="float:left">
            <tr>
                <td>Employee id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Designation</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <select id="select_id" style="float:right">
            <option>--select--</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select><br/><br/>

        <button onclick="delete_row()" style="float:right">remove</button>
        <button onclick="include()" style="float:right">add</button>

</body>
```

My javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var employees=new Array(2);

        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
            employees[i] = new Array(3);

        employees[0][0] = 1;
        employees[0][1] = "Rahul";
        employees[0][2] = "Administer";

        employees[1][0] = 2;
        employees[1][1] = "Raj";
        employees[1][2] = "Manager";

        function include(){
            var id = document.getElementById("select_id").value;
            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            var row = table.insertRow();
            id=id-1;

            var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var col2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var col3 = row.insertCell(2);

            col1.innerHTML = employees[id][0];
            col2.innerHTML = employees[id][1];
            col3.innerHTML = employees[id][2];
        }
    </script>
```

Add button works fine. but for remove button I cant get a function to remove all the rows with selected id. Can anyone suggest me?

My code in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/noona/fNPvf/23235/

Comment: this question is not clear, if you add many rows of 1 (1, rahul, Administer) then how would you define delete criteria as there will be many rows of this. do you want to remove all rows of record 1 ?

Comment: I would suggest you to bind a check box along with each rows, So that you will be able to get a selected id and then try to execute the delete code. I hope this makes an idea

Comment: @UmerHayyat yup..thatz my question

Comment: @NooNaMarJa ok, let me update your fiddle

Comment: @Jayaraj.K That requires jquery ?

Comment: @UmerHayyat Fine.. :)

Comment: Yes . You requires a jquery

Comment: @NooNaMarJa https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/23238/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use querySelectorAll and rowIndex to achieve this. here is your updated code

```js
var employees = new Array(2);

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  employees[i] = new Array(3);

employees[0][0] = 1;
employees[0][1] = "Rahul";
employees[0][2] = "Administer";

employees[1][0] = 2;
employees[1][1] = "Raj";
employees[1][2] = "Manager";

function include() {
  var id = document.getElementById("select_id").value;
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = table.insertRow();
  id = id - 1;
  row.id = id;
  var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var col2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var col3 = row.insertCell(2);

  col1.innerHTML = employees[id][0];
  col2.innerHTML = employees[id][1];
  col3.innerHTML = employees[id][2];
}

function delete_row() {
  var id = document.getElementById("select_id").value - 1;
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  rowsCount = table.querySelectorAll('tr[id="' + id + '"');

  for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount.length; i++) {
    table.deleteRow(rowsCount[i].rowIndex);
  }

}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1" style="float:left">
  <tr>
    <td>Employee id</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Designation</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<select id="select_id" style="float:right">
  <option>--select--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>

<button onclick="delete_row()" style="float:right">remove</button>
<button onclick="include()" style="float:right">add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

When adding a new row, give the newly added rows an attribute that holds it's id value. Then you can delete all the rows whose attribute value is equal to selected id in dropmenu. 
you can try below:

```
function include(){
var table = document.getElementById("table");
        var id = document.getElementById("select_id").value;
        var table = document.getElementById("table");
        var row = table.insertRow();

        // give the new row an attribute that can identify itself
        row.setAttribute("emplId",id);

        id=id-1;

        var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var col2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var col3 = row.insertCell(2);

        col1.innerHTML = employees[id][0];
        col2.innerHTML = employees[id][1];
        col3.innerHTML = employees[id][2];

    }

function delete_row() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var id = document.getElementById("select_id").value;
    for(var i = 0; i<table.rows.length; i++) { // iterate through the rows
        var rowEmplId = table.rows[i].getAttribute("emplId");
        if(rowEmplId==id) { // found a row matches the selected option
            table.deleteRow(i); // remove this row
            i--; // we just removed a row, so we need to adjust the cursor   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jin Ming or Why iterating over all rows in the table? querySelectorAll can get all that rows having id like table.querySelectorAll('tr[id="' + id + '"')